# How to prevent django migrations from running?

Tags: django, django-migrations

My team frequently uses the production DB for testing new changes and on more than one occasion migrations have been created and applied before being code reviewed, creating issues in production.

There are so many things wrong with this situation, but I'm hoping to at least protect our prod DB by blocking migrations based on the state of an environment variable. Is this possible?

Comment: Running tests against a production database is asking for trouble whichever way you look at it. I don't think the approach you have proposed in your answer really helps - in fact it's just going to break your project so that any tests run in that state have no meaning anyway (removing from installed apps doesn't just prevent migrations, it prevents the app from working at all). I appreciate that this doesn't provide an altogether helpful answer to your specific question, but the only way to really fix this is *not to test unapproved changes in production*.

Comment: Also, how can you meaningfully test any changes unless all relevant database migrations have been applied? This does feel like an XY problem.

Comment: Sorry, the context I gave was pretty vague... for "testing new changes" I more meant testing features and business logic, not migrations. But always using the production DB to test feature changes means that when the need to test a migration comes up, folks forget to switch back to their dev DB and set up their environment there, then they end up running migrations on prod before their migration is approved.

I know the correct thing to do here is to not use the production DB for any local development, but we're kinda scrappy right now - so we'll compromise with blocking migrations for now.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like it might work, but curious if others have less hacky answers:

```
# Prevent migrations from running in dev env (where the prod DB is used).
if ENVIRONMENT == 'staging' and 'migrate' in sys.argv:
    INSTALLED_APPS.remove('app_name')
```

Answer (score 0):

So we tackled it like this. Instead of one `settings.py` file we have multiple different ones `settings/dev.py`, `settings/prod.py`, `settings/local.py` etc.

Then when you do any `manage.py` command, you need to explicitly add which settings file you want to use.

```sh
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=myapp.settings.dev ./manage.py migrate
```

we speed this up with a `manage.sh` file next to `manage.py` that kinda looks like this:

```sh
EXPECTED_ENVS=(local development staging production)
if [[ ${EXPECTED_ENVS[*]} =~ "$1" ]]
then
    # Pop the first argument parameters after 1
    SETTINGS_ENV=$1
    shift 1
else
    SETTINGS_ENV="local"
fi

export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="myapp.settings.${SETTINGS_ENV}"
echo "Using settings module ${DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE}"

./manage.py $@
```

Then you can simply do things like this

```sh
./manage.sh development migrate
./manage.sh production shell
./manage.sh local runserver
```

with the above code, omitting the environment name will use the "local" settings file.

```sh
./manage.sh runserver # uses local as default
```